# How does a Rust PathBuf prevent directory traversal attacks?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

From [*"A Case for Oxidation: The Rust Programming Language"*](https://youtu.be/cDFSrVhnZKo?t=2063) Sergio Benitez says,

> Here is a static file server written in Rocket. It is exactly four lines and it guaranteed to **not** be vulnerable to directory traversal attacks.

Those four lines are:

```
#[get("/<path..>")]
fn files(path: PathBuf) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    NamedFile::open(Path::new("static/").join(path)).ok()
}
```

The bottom of this slide says,

- `FromParam*` implementation for `PathBuf` verifies path safety

I get how a type can guarantee safety by validating input (in the same sense that any object can in a constructor or how the input to a function can be wrapped with a validating function.

```
dangerousThing(validateSafety(input))
```

Many languages provide this. I also understand how you can make this simpler by putting it into a constructor for a type or class,

```
class Path {
  constructor(path) { this._path = validateSafety(path) }
}
```

But I'm confused at what (if anything) Rust is doing differently here. Is there anything more to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PathBuf` provides no such guarantees. It *cannot* because there's no concept of "directory traversal attacks" in all domains where a `PathBuf` is used.

What the author means is that the implementation of [`FromSegments`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/request/trait.FromSegments.html) for `PathBuf` performs the traversal attack check and never calls the handler if it fails.

`FromSegments` allows for failure cases by returning a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html):

```
pub trait FromSegments<'a>: Sized {
    type Error: Debug;
    fn from_segments(segments: Segments<'a>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>;
}
```

Comment: So it's just a constructor for a type that takes in input, checks for `../` (or a parent-notation), and fails to create the type in runtime if one is detected?

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate over parts of path with `components()`, so we can check `..` usage like shown as below :

```
let p = PathBuf::from_str("/tmp/../etc/password").unwrap();
if p.components().into_iter().any(|x| x == Component::ParentDir) {
    return Err("directory traversal");
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need .into_iter(), `Components` is already an iterator. 2. While this example makes sense in isolation, it doesn't really address the common case where are joining relative path components to some base dir, because `.push()` replaces the path on joining another absolute path. Instead, finish constructing the path, canonicalise (e.g. with `fs::canonicalize`), and then check you are still inside your base directory.